# JSON file messing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am making a Twitch bot in node.js and I have ran into a few weird issues.

I have a JSON file system set up, which can be manipulated via commands in the chat. However, for some reason, the JSON file's formatting messes up terribly upon inputting wrong data (such as not defining the user or giving letters/characters instead of a number). A well formatted JSON file will turn into a one-line monster and will often totally mess up the file contents when inputting even more wrong stuff.

The weird part is, that I have set up a detection system for wrong input which should return an error message and ignore writing to the JSON file, however that does not work for some reason (Error message appears, JSON file still changes).

I am a pretty novice programmer so go easy If I may ask.

```js
if (userName === "xyz1" || userName === "xyz2") {  // censored for privacy
  if (!args[0] || !args[1]) return client.say(channelName, 'You did not specify the user or the value)!');

  const user = args[0].toLowerCase();
  const giveRaw = args[1];

  if (!giveRaw.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) return client.say(channelName, 'Your amount cannot contain letters/symbols/decimals!');

  const giveInt = parseInt(giveRaw);

  if (pointsjson.hasOwnProperty(user)) {
    pointsjson[user] = {
      points: pointsjson[user].points + giveInt
    }

    fs.writeFile('./system/points.json', JSON.stringify(pointsjson, null, 10), err => {  // write to json
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    client.say(channelName, `Added ${giveInt} coins to ${user}'s balance.`);
  } else if (pointsjson.hasOwnProperty(user) === false) {
    pointsjson[user] = {
      points: giveInt
    }

    fs.writeFile("./system/points.json", JSON.stringify(pointsjson, null, 10), err => {  // write to json
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    client.say(channelName, `Added ${giveInt} coins to ${user}'s balance. (User has no record in database, added points anyways, did you input the name correctly?)`);
  }
} else if (userName !== 'xyz1' && userName !== 'xyz2') return client.say(channelName, "Can't do that broski! (Developer only command.)");
```

Comment: Could many users be writing to and reading from `points.json` simultaneously? The code does not seem to await the `writeFile` callback. Simultaneously attempting reads and writes to the same file can cause corruption. NodeJS docs advise: "It is unsafe to use fs.writeFile() multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream() is recommended." See if `fs.writeFileSync("./system/points.json", JSON.stringify(pointsjson, null, 10))` stops corruption. Also, perhaps consider a lightweight JSON database for Node to handle this complexity for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the corruption is still present, but If I can't resolve it within the few days I will probably look into some module which can do the writing for me, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you add an example of the simplest "wrong data" input that causes corruption, the actual JSON output in this case, and the error message text you're getting?

Comment: Okay, let me break it down. There is a command called /give, which requires 2 arguments, first being the username, second being the points to give. When the user inputs something, a regex will inspect the 2nd argument if its a number or not, if it's not, it should return the error message in the channel and don't write anything to the JSON, however, the error message DOES get sent, but the json still messes up even when nothing is being written to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Apparently I messed up JSON.stringify() somewhere in my code, which got triggered every time a message was sent. I feel so dumb.